# How to login to local account in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I tried to login to local account. The name of the account is placesiwanttovisit.

It seems that windows 10 think placesiwanttovisit is a microsoft account and reject the credential.

[image]

[image]

See that MicrosoftAccount\placesiwanttovisit

placesiwanttovisit is not a microsoft account. It's a local account

Comment: That's not how Microsoft Accounts are accessed, MicrosoftAccount appears to be a domain, but based on the username alone it's not possible for it to be an actual Microsoft Account, if the account isn't a domain account don't provide it a domain.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `.\placesiwanttovisit` will do the trick as `.` will refer to the computer you try to access.